# Kubernetes: Access of external Systems from Pods don't work

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kubernetes, iptables, minikube

I am trying to access **within** a kubernetes pod (inside minikube-VM) to an **external** Zookeeper/Kafka ( outside kubernetes-domain) ,which basically doesn't work.

First, I have a docker-image, which runs a Spring-Boot Application and it tries to connect on startup a Kafka-Instance on Port 2181/9092 respectably.  As I have created a Service with an Endpoint, that points to the external Host/IP that should fix the routing, but unfortunately it doesn't.

Here is the definition of the service/endpoint

```html
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ext-kafka
  namespace: default
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 2181
    name: zk
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 2181
  - port: 9092
    name: kafka
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9092
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: ext-kafka
  namespace: default
subsets:
- addresses:
  # 192.168.99.1 is the external IP
  - ip: 192.168.99.1
  ports:
  - port: 2181
    name: zk
  - port: 9092
    name: kafka


#
# HERE ARE THE DEPLOYMENTS/DEFINITIONS THAT THE SERVICES ARE INSTALLED
#
[root@centos1 work]# kubectl get services
NAME                      CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
ext-kafka                 None         <none>        2181/TCP,9092/TCP   2d

 ...

[root@centos1 work]# kubectl get endpoints
NAME                      ENDPOINTS                             AGE
ext-kafka                 192.168.99.1:2181,192.168.99.1:9092   2d
```

I checked the iptables on the minikube VM, as it stated that Packages getting denied. So cleaning up doesn't resolve the Issue, as it gets recreated automatically behind the scenes.

```html
$ iptables -L
....

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
KUBE-SERVICES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes service portals */

...

Chain KUBE-FIREWALL (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets */ mark match 0x8000/0x8000

Chain KUBE-SERVICES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
....
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* default/server-command: has no endpoints */ ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL tcp dpt:30021 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             10.0.0.240           /* default/server-command: has no endpoints */ tcp dpt:webcache 

....
```

Another approach to ease the constellation:

I run ncat with `ncat -l 192.168.99.1 2181 --keep-open`
on the host, where zookeeper/Kafka should run
and tried to connect from the minikube-VM with
`telnet 192.168.99.1 2181`
I got 'no rotue to host' ...

So how to get sovle the issue??
How to add a Service, which resolves the iptables- Problem?
( I used the kubernetes build from BuildDate:"2017-05-10T15:48:59Z" )

BR

Comment: Can you ping `192.168.99.1` and also what is the output of `ip a` on the minikube vm? Also are you sure the **external Zookeeper/Kafka** is bound to interface with ip `192.168.99.1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using Minikube, I think the issue is because of the Zookeeper/Kafka  IP Address (192.168.99.1). You can see that Minikube is working on the network 192.168.99.0/24 by doing `minikube ssh` and executing `ip addr`

```
  3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 08:00:27:97:6c:ed brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.99.100/24 brd 192.168.99.255 scope global dynamic eth1
   valid_lft 798sec preferred_lft 798sec
inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe97:6ced/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Therefore, if the zookeeper/kafka is supposed to be outside the Minikube network, there may be a conflict with the IP. I would advise you to use a different IP (for example: 192.168.200.xx) for this external service.

Comment: Hello Javier! Your suggestion helped me out! Many thanks. I used another network interface and the communication worked.